# question about function and class names having similar name

Tags: flash

wouldn't there be any naming collision
cause in this case, function name and class name both are named DocumentClass
can someone explain it in layman's terms
cause i'm still a newbie in flash as3

```
package com.identityMine.documentClass
{
   import flash.display.MovieClip;
   public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip
   {
      public function DocumentClass()
   {

  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be the constructor - which is called whenever you create an instance of the class.

Think of it as this.. When you say:

```
var thing:MyClass = new MyClass();
```

You're:

1. Creating a new instance of MyClass.
2. Calling the MyClass() method.

Other languages use different methods, for example to define the constructor of a class in PHP you use `__construct()` like so:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'hello, I exist now';
    }
}
```

So creating an instance of this class like so, would output *'hello, I exist now'* onto the page.

```
<?php $thing = new MyClass(); ?>
```

Comment: yeah, i got it thanks bro!
what about the namespace in package
can you explain it to me!
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

In this case the function is the **constructor** of the class. It has to have the name of the class. This constructor function will be executed each time you create a new instance of your class.

Comment: why is it so?
why should a constructor like you said has to have the same name as the class?

Comment: its by definition in AS3. Other languages may implement this in other ways.

Comment: @christian: but why? Each programming language has its on syntax. i.e. c# also uses the class name for the constructor.

Comment: @DanielB one more question bro! why is the package has a succeeding identifier in this case com.identityMine.documentClass
they say it's a namespace then if it is then what is a namespace?
sorry bro! i'm a newbie in flash

Comment: @DanielB so you mean it's basically an identifier!
as if it's like just a name tag!
am i right?

Comment: more a type of categorization but with access restrictions. all classes within the same namespace can access the others without any further implementation. classes from other namespaces have to "import" the other namespaces is a way like in your example `import flash.display.MovieClip;`